# Stateless vs Statefull beans: разница понятий

Tags: java, ejb

Добрый день!
Очень нужен работающий пример, демонстрирующий разницу понятий.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужен никакой пример. Stateful может хранить какое-либо состояние между запросами, соответственно контейнер имеет пул таких бинов и для каждой сессии выделяет отдельный экземпляр. Stateless никакого состояния не хранит, а следовательно может использоваться один и тот же экземпляр. Вроде же все понятно.

Comment: Звучит понятно, а вот *увидеть вживую* не получается!
Вот пост http://javatalks.ru/topics/42185?page=1#215194

Comment: @voipp сомневаюсь, что к исключению приводит вызов метода. Нет стэктрейса, доказывающего это. Да и само исключение говорит скорее об ошибке деплоймента и отсутствии класса.

Comment: @a_gura в том то и прикол, что второй метод нормально вызывается и нормально срабатывает! Здесь какая-то внутренняя причина для исключения

Comment: @voipp Еще раз: я не вижу доказательств того, о чем вы говорите. `get` должен отрабатывать так же, как и `set`. Разница лишь в том, что нельзя полагаться на то, что состояние не изменили в другой сессии.

Comment: @a_gura вот лог со стэк трейсом : http://pastebin.com/rBS3MjSC
а вот проект если интересно: https://github.com/voipp/EJBExample.git
Деплой и сборку делал правильно.
Для удобства выложил код ниже

Comment: @voipp Ну и что мы видим в стектрейсе: эксепшн происходит при вызове `setState`, а не `getState`, как вы утверждали. Я не в курсе премудростей инжекшна в EJB, но подозреваю, что происходит это либо отложенно (lazy), либо инжектится заглушка или прокси, который и пытается загрузить нужный класс и не находит его.

Comment: @a_gura инжектится заглушка, она производит rmi вызов. Я в печали(

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by voipp on 28/05/2014.
*/
public class clientRunner {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("loggerSample");

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Runnable task = new someClient(i);
        Thread worker = new Thread(task);

        worker.setName("client" + String.valueOf(i));

        worker.start();

        threads.add(worker);
    }
    int running = 0;
    do {
        running = 0;
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            if (thread.isAlive()) {
                running++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("We have " + running + " running threads. ");
    } while (running > 0);

}

}

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public class someClient  implements Runnable {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("loggerSample");

@EJB
private IStatelessBean bean;

Integer personalId;

public someClient(Integer i) {
    this.personalId = i;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        log.info("Beginning new thread with id= " + personalId);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            log.info("client " + personalId + " set " + i);
            bean.setState(i);

            log.info("client " + personalId + " get " + bean.getState());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
       log.info("error =C " , e);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
        log.info("error =C " , e);
    }

}
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Remote
public interface IStatelessBean {

void setState(Integer i);
Integer getState();

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;

 @Stateless
public class StatelessBean implements IStatelessBean {

public void setState(Integer state) {
    this.state = state;
}

private Integer state = 0;

@Override
public Integer getState() {
    return state;
}
}
```

Comment: Это явно не ответ. Ссылки на github думаю достаточно.